# How can i avoid similar foreach conditions?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iterator

I'm having a code in which i'm using mutiple arrays and foreach statement. Most of the code is pretty similar so i was thinking to change these lines of code but i'm clueless

```
$requiredProducts = Array
(
    [62861] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6910
            [1] => 17118
            [2] => 32218
            [3] => 39134
            [4] => 39154
            [5] => 39156
        )

    [57590] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39156
            [1] => 39192
            [2] => 39200
        )

)

foreach ($requiredProducts as $vehicleId => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $productId) {
        $webOrderVehicleProductId = (!empty($currentProducts[$vehicleId][$productId])) ?
            $currentProducts[$vehicleId][$productId] : null;
        $products[$vehicleId][] = $this->prepareProduct(
            $webOrderVehicleProductId,
            $productId,
            $this->getConfig()->constant->default->PRODUCT_QUANTITY,
            isset($priceInfo['productsInfo']['productWithInfo'][$productId]['price']) ?
                $priceInfo['productsInfo']['productWithInfo'][$productId]['price'] : 0,
            $this->getConfig()->constant->default->ARCHIVE_STATUS
        );
    }
}

$transitPlates = Array
(
    [62861] => 545,
    [57590] => 848
)

foreach ($transitPlates as $vehicleId => $transitPlateId) {
    $webOrderVehicleProductId = (!empty($currentProducts[$vehicleId][$transitPlateId])) ?
        $currentProducts[$vehicleId][$transitPlateId] : null;
    $products[$vehicleId][] = $this->prepareProduct(
        $webOrderVehicleProductId,
        $transitPlateId,
        $this->getConfig()->constant->default->PRODUCT_QUANTITY,
        isset($priceInfo['productsInfo']['transitPlateWithInfo'][$transitPlateId]['price']) ?
                $priceInfo['productsInfo']['transitPlateWithInfo'][$transitPlateId]['price'] : 0,
        $this->getConfig()->constant->default->ARCHIVE_STATUS
    );
}

$dieselProducts = Array
(
    [62861] => Array
        (
            [39156] => 200
            [39192] => 96
        )
)

$dieselProductId = Basweb_Shared_Model_Entity_Product::PRODUCT_DIESEL_ID;
    foreach ($dieselProducts as $vehicleId => $data) {
        $webOrderVehicleProductId = (!empty($currentProducts[$vehicleId][$dieselProductId])) ?
            $currentProducts[$vehicleId][$dieselProductId] : null;
        $products[$vehicleId][] = $this->prepareProduct(
            $webOrderVehicleProductId,
            $dieselProductId,
            $data[$dieselProductId]['quantity'],
            isset($priceInfo['dieselPrice']) ? $priceInfo['dieselPrice'] : 0,
            $this->getConfig()->constant->default->ARCHIVE_STATUS
    );
}

$tyres = Array
(
    [62861] => Array
        (
            [front_1] => 39156
            [rare_1] => 39192
        )
)

foreach ($tyres as $vehicleId => $tyre) {
    foreach ($tyre as $axle => $productId) {
        $tyreOffers = isset($priceInfo['tyreInfo'][$vehicleId][$axle]) ?
            $priceInfo['tyreInfo'][$vehicleId][$axle] : array();
        $webOrderVehicleProductId = (!empty($currentProducts[$vehicleId][$productId][$axle])) ?
            $currentProducts[$vehicleId][$productId][$axle] : null;
        $products[$vehicleId][] = $this->prepareProduct(
            $webOrderVehicleProductId,
            $productId,
            $this->getConfig()->constant->default->TYRE_QUANTITY,
            $this->getTyrePrice($productId, $tyreOffers),
            $this->getConfig()->constant->default->ARCHIVE_STATUS,
            $axle
        );
    }
}
```

I tried searching for recursive array iterator to avoid multiple foreach but no luck so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welp, overall you have several options, at their very core they do the same thing, arguably one may do better than another performance wise. So, you can do [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-walk-recursive.php), [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)(which has a silly name), [`RecursiveIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php) and the classic recursion and a few others which I left out. I suppose one would choose whatever he/she is more comfortable with.

Comment: Thank @Andrew i tried RecursiveIteratorIterator

```
$result = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($requiredProducts));
        foreach($result as $k => $v){
            echo $k.'===';
            echo $v.'<br>';
        }
0===6910
1===17118
2===32218
3===39134
4===39154
5===39156
0===39156
1===39192
2===39200
```
But it is giving result something like this. How will apply my logic on this?